# Matching variables in template metaprogramming c++

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

I am writing a class in TMP to do some basic string processing. A string is represented as a class variadic template of chars. I want to test if two strings are equal and, if they are, have an associated type present, but I don't know how I would test if two chars are equal at compile-time. My current code looks as follows but doesn't compile for obvious reasons.

```
template <typename T, char firstChar, char... Chrs>
class NamedType
{
public:
    typedef T Type;

    template <char otherFirst, char... OtherChrs>
    class TypeIfMatch
    {
    };

    template <firstChar, char... OtherChrs>
    class TypeIfMatch
    {
    public:
         typedef NamedType<T, Chrs>::TypeIfMatch<OtherChars>::type type;
    };

    template <>
    class TypeIfMatch
    {
    public:
         typedef Type type;
    };

    static const char name[sizeof...(Chrs) + 1];
};
```

template const char NamedType::name[sizeof...(Chrs)+1] = {Chrs..., '\0'};

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the strings are specializations of a variadic template, just compare the types for equality via [`std::is_same`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same). The resulting type is an [`std::integral_constant`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integral_constant) with `bool` as the value type -- specifically, either `std::true_type` or `std::false_type`.